# Не срабатывает hide() внутри setTiemout()

Tags: jquery, settimeout, hide

Использую hide()/show() в карусели. При смене отображаемого блока новый появляется, а предыдущий исчезает. Если использовать просто hide() без setTimeout(), то блок исчезает мгновенно и все это портит анимацию.
Хочу задать исчезновение через определенный промежуток времени, но hide() внутри setTimeout() отказывает работать.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $allCarouselInners[$activeElement-1].hide();
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: [$activeElement-1] попробуйте в круглые скобки -( [$activeElement-1] ).hide();

Comment: @LenovoID В данном случае это обращение к элементу массива. Скобки не имеют смысла.

Comment: достаточно значение времени передать в качестве аргумента в `hide` ...... тобишь `$allCarouselInners[$activeElement-1].hide(1000);` ..... а также можно её же задать и плавность и другие опции http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский hide(1000) это время выполнения анимации, а у него задержка требуется ПЕРЕД анимацией

Comment: ошибки консоли в студию.

Comment: это все из-за того, что активный элемент мог смениться, до того как сработал таймер, без [mcve] не угадать почему именно не работает

Comment: andrey1990 я спорить не буду - я тоже не уверен был